# What is the essential gear to have in a VHF/UHF FM base station?

Tags: equipment, 70cm-band, 2m-band, fm

I'm trying to assemble a VHF/UHF FM base-station at home. Assuming I have the following pieces of equipment:

1. VHF/UHF FM transceiver
2. power supply - 30 amps, no meters
3. antenna that's resonant on 2m and 70cm and a way to mount it
4. proper grounding
5. cabling to link them all together

What other gear and equipment, besides the list above, would most hams consider essential or at least highly recommend having at hand? The intended use of the station is local repeater and simplex operation for casual contacts, net participation, and possibly emergency operations (RACES/ARES).

To further clarify what I'm trying to ask, would any of the following be considered essential or at least really really useful to have under the above scenario with the previously mentioned equipment?

- dummy load
- ammeter/multimeter (assuming the power supply doesn't display amperage)
- in-line antenna tuner
- informational resources (maps, log books, etc)

Comment: The answers to this are as broad as the applications of radio.

Comment: Can you offer a suggestion on how I can narrow the question down?

Comment: You will have to pick a direction. Do you want to do DX PSK31 on 20m? Do you want to homebrew antennas? Do you want to work satellites? If you ask about HF, VHF, or UHF, that covers pretty much the whole of amateur radio. The only essential gear common to all of this *is* the obvious stuff, like a power cord, maybe a microphone... The non-obvious stuff only comes into play if you have a non-obvious application.

Comment: So is the answer that there's no other gear outside of my list that most hams would consider essential for good base-station operations regardless of mode or intended use?

Comment: Besides obvious stuff, no. You don't have any problem to have a solution. You haven't even suggested an application, so we can't even guess at what your problems might be. One could envision a list of things that are nice, or common, but are they essential? The merits of each piece of equipment in a typical shack could merit a question of its own, and every station is going to have different goals and preferences.

Comment: Let me try modifying the question.

Comment: Have a care with the selection of coax to go from your station to the antenna.  The typical mobile coax of RG58 or the inexpensive RG-8X both have pretty significant loses at VHF/UHF frequencies.  If it's a short run or you are just hitting local repeaters, this may not matter much.  If you are looking for longer range communications, then that loss will hurt.

Comment: @AndrewKG6ABV this is still a [list question](http://meta.ham.stackexchange.com/questions/12/how-about-list-questions). There are infinitely many answers, it will never be complete, and everyone has a different idea of what's "essential".

Comment: If this is the wrong venue for this type of question, please close it.

Answer (score 3):

Based on my somewhat short experience as a ham, these are some of the things I find very useful in my shack or would like to have:

- a comfy chair
- paper/writing instruments and/or computer for logging purposes
- a hook or clippy thing to hang your microphone from (if you're not using a desk or boom mic)
- shelves. you can never have enough shelves in the shack.
- a 24-h clock set for UTC time.
- Maps of the ITU and CQ zones
- ARRL band plan chart
- external speakers for your radio
- SWR/power meter

given that your antenna is resonant at 2m/70cm, an antenna tuner wouldn't be necessary unless you decide to start experimenting with other antennas.
Dummy load would be useful if you need to test your radio for some purpose.

Comment: How about adding a combined SWR/power meter to the list?  I realize its not much use if nothing goes wrong, but it would be the first troubleshooting instrument in the case of problems.

Comment: ooo ya. didn't think of that one because my rig already shows me tx power and swr. Definitely handy for radios that don't indicate one or the other.

Comment: Is a microphone essential if you operate CW or digital modes? What about the computer to do those digital modes? Is a 24hr clock or a national or world map *essential* for VHF/UHF operation? This answer is entirely subjective, and not backed by any reference or fact.

Answer (score 2):

Trouble shooting equipment such as an antenna analyzer and VOM, replacement parts (PL-259's, etc), a soldering iron.  Provisions for expansion as needed (another operator at your station during a disaster, etc.)

Your initial list is a great start but it assumes nothing is going to go wrong.

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by "provisions for expansion"?

Comment: More radios for other operators.